# Disable "error messages" in Discord.NET 1.0

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I've rewritten my bot completely from scratch, because I needed the `RequireUserPermission` for a certain command. It works, but I have a slight problem.

Every time a user tries to run this command without the needed permission, a message is sent by the bot.

E.g.:

> User requires guild permission SendTTSMessages

I don't want this message to be sent. Is there a way to disable these error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

Within your `CommandHandler` There should be code similar to

```
if (!result.IsSuccess)
{
    await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ToString());
}
```

You can just remove this line of code, to prevent error disclosure.
However, this will make your life hard when trying to debug future errors and issues.

So instead, you might want to create some sort of toggle on/off variable so that you can toggle it on/ off.

```
bool Debug = true;
if (!result.IsSuccess && Debug)
{
     await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ToString());
}
```